# Service Broker - Making trigger for outputing xml file

Tags: sql-server, bcp, service-broker

Good day.

I have main task to do is next:

"Some" programm that has databases `MonitorEDTest` and `DecNet` in MSSQL 2012, i need to make an xml-file with detailed information from 4-5 tables in this database, which creates when `StatusId` of one entry becomes `150`.

Now, i'm trying to solve this like this:

1. I made trigger on table with column StatusId, so it triggers when StatusId is 150. Made it with cursor for multiple entries with this status.

   ```
   ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[DT_Update_NEW]
   ON [MonitorEDTest].[dbo].[LOG_DECL]
   FOR UPDATE
   AS 
   BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
       if exists (select * from inserted where StatusId = 150)
       begin
           declare @nd nvarchar (100), @ProcessId nvarchar (100)
           declare DTcursor cursor for
           select [ND], [ProcessId] from inserted
           open DTcursor;
           FETCH NEXT FROM DTcursor into @nd, @ProcessId

           WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
           BEGIN

                       exec dbo.DT_info_Broker @nd, @ProcessId

                       FETCH NEXT FROM DTcursor into @nd, @ProcessId

           END

           CLOSE DTcursor
           deallocate DTcursor
       end
   END
   ```
2. Then this trigger uses procedure `dbo.DT_info_Broker` that creates full xml-file with `select...join..for xml` statements, after that full xml code sends with service broker to himself (made ServiceBroker on base `MonitorEDTest` which contains table for trigger, and whole info takes from other DB `DecNet`).

   ```
   ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DT_Info_Broker] 
   @nd nvarchar (200), @ProcessId nvarchar (200)
   AS
   BEGIN
       SET NOCOUNT ON;
       declare @base nvarchar(100), @g07 nvarchar(1000), @sql nvarchar (MAX), @flag int, @code1 nvarchar (2000), @code2 nvarchar (1000), @code3 nvarchar (1000), @code4 nvarchar(1000), @code nvarchar(4000), @codeold nvarchar (1000),
   @bat nvarchar(1000), @pwshell nvarchar(1000), @batdel nvarchar(1000), @msg xml

       set @base = 'DecNet'

       set @msg = (SELECT (select.....)for xml path(''), root('DT'))
       declare @ch uniqueidentifier

       begin dialog conversation @ch from service Monitor to service 'Monitor' on contract [Monitor_Contract] with encryption = off

       select @ch, @nd, @g07, @msg

       ;send on conversation @ch message type [Monitor_Message] (@msg) 

       EXEC [MonitorEDTest].[dbo].[Que_Broker]
   END
   ```
3. Then i had two ideas, first i tried to make `activation procedure` for Service Broker (SB) to make it like trigger for sending xml from 2., but it didn’t work, so after sending to SB I executed another procedure `dbo.Que_Broker`.
4. This procedure is similar to how people usually “receives” message from SB, code is above. Also on that procedure I take from ready xml-code one tag `g07` for making name of xml output file like `@g07.xml` ~ `10000000-170718-0000000.xml`

   ```
   ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Que_Broker] 
   AS
   BEGIN
       while 1 = 1
       begin
           declare @command nvarchar(2000), @xmlint int, @XmlText nvarchar(max), @g07 nvarchar (100)
           declare @count int, @ch uniqueidentifier, @retvalue bit --, @msgtype sysname, @body varbinary(max)

           select @count = count(*) from Monitor_Queue
           if (@count = 0) break

           set @xmlint = 0
           select top (1) @XmlText = cast(message_body as nvarchar(max)), @ch = conversation_handle from Monitor_Queue where message_type_name = 'Monitor_Message' order by conversation_handle
           exec sp_xml_preparedocument @xmlint OUTPUT, @XmlText
           select @g07 = [text] from OPENXML (@xmlint, 'DT', 1) where [parentid] = 4
           exec sp_XML_removedocument @xmlint
           set @g07 = (select replace (@g07, '/', '-'))
           set @command = 'bcp "receive top (1) cast(message_body as xml) from Monitor_Queue" queryout D:\' + @g07 + '.xml -T -x -c -C 1251 -d MonitorEDTest'
           select @command, @g07
           --waitfor delay '00:00:01'
           EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @command

           --break
           end conversation @ch with cleanup

       end
   END
   ```

So **the main problem** is next, i wrote on last procedure code which goes to Queues of SB and while it has count>0 it makes `bcp “receive top (1) cast(message_body as xml) from Monitor_Queue”...queryout “*.xml”`
Then the conversation ends.

When i was checking how it works, everything worked fine, but bcp didn’t copy any entry of BS and when i check messages in table queue, the message still there. When i’m trying to execute that procedure manually bcp works fine.

```
output
------------
NULL
Starting copy...
NULL
0 rows copied.
Network packet size (bytes): 4096
Clock Time (ms.) Total     : 1     
NULL
```

Also before idea with SB, i tried to do something like that with creating dynamic steps in job with `sp_update_jobstep` and `sp_start_job`, but it didn’t work, because of multiple entry within one time (like update top 5 set statusid = 150 where statusid = 150). Job couldn’t be opened by next entry because first didn’t finish.

Sorry for some mistakes, but first time writing here, hope to see some help and learn more of using sql, because I learned everything by myself and from some courses.

Comment: I think, I solved this without using SB. Deleted [dbo].[Que_Broker] and switched method of opening dialog in [dbo].[DT_Info_Broker] on procedure that:

EXECUTE sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream',  @OLE OUTPUT

which can create xml-file even in UTF-8. Still need some LIVE tests.

Comment: First live testing went successful, going to test more, but still this thread can be closed, I liked how it worked even for frirst time. Thank you for all viewers :)